# what's the most frequent word across many files

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing

what's the most efficient algorithm to find the most frequent word across many files(distributed across several machines)?

Each machine can give the most frequent word -or the count of any word- exists in its file.

Is there an algorithm or a technique to find the answer -deterministic- without asking each machine for all the words?  if not what's the best way to give a close answer with as little as possible number of queries to the machines.

Comment: run the calculation on each machine, then merge, very trivial. start from shell scripts and scp command to synchronize files. if (and only if) performance is not enough rewrite in compiled language.

Comment: this means I need to ask each machine for all of its results, and that was I need to minimize

Comment: I would make a guess that indexing the machine's filesystem is much slower than scp-ing results around

Comment: Are you trying to avoid asking each machine for *all* words, or *any* words? Assuming the former, what is your cost to ask each machine for (let's say) top 100 words? Is it much lower than asking it for all words?

Comment: @DariusX. yes, I'm avoiding asking for all the words. Let's say asking for all the words will be like asking for each word one by one, so it's slower than any other thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have K machines. From each machine request the most frequent word, send these K words to each machine and total their frequency over all machines. Let the frequency of the most common word be N.

In next step, from each machine request list of all words which have frequency of at least N/K. Aggregate this list and send to each machine. Collect back frequencies across machines, sum them and find the most frequent word overall. This word is guaranteed to be the most frequent word.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how did you conduct the N/K condition? it seems to work

Comment: If any word NOT in the first list is the top word, then it should have at least N occurrences. In the worst case it should be distributed evenly on each machine. So at least one machine must have N/K occurrences.

Comment: This would actually be **K times worse** than just aggregating all the lists to one machine in the worst case. Consider when the most frequent word on each machine occurs K times and doesn't appear on any other machine. `K/K` = 1, then we'd be getting all words from all machines and much worse yet, we'd be sending this list back to all machines, and then they'd be sending all their frequencies back again to be aggregated.

Comment: @Dukeling I am assuming that the frequency of words follows roughly the zipf's distribution.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to split the work done between the machines.

Have a hash function that hashes each word to a number between `1` and `K` - this corresponds to the machine that the frequency of that word will be sent to.

So, let each machine send their frequencies to the applicable machines.

After this, let each machine sum up the frequencies received.

Then let each machine send their most frequent word to some machine and let that machine simply find the maximum.

Since the calculated hash will always be same for some given word, all frequencies for that word will be sent to the same machine, so the sum that that machine calculates will be the total frequency for that word.

**Running time:**

With a perfect hash function, this would be done in `O(N + K)` time, where `N` is the number of word frequencies per machine and `K` is the total number of machines, since a lot of the work will be parallelized - more precisely, each machine will send `O(N)` frequencies, and each machine will receive `O(N)` frequencies and aggregate that. Then each machine will send its most frequent word to one machine, which that machine will find the maximum of, which would take `O(K)`. This could perhaps be optimized to `O(N + log K)` if we were to cleverly pass the highest frequencies between the machines (think merge-sort).

In the worst case however, this would take `O(NK)`, since one machine will receive `O(NK)` frequencies.